# Aggregate out from Multiple Collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How I can output result of MongoDB aggregation into collection without replacing the collection from another aggregation output?

I need to get data only with $out: 'tempCollection', because I have 500mln documents, and getting [pipeline stage limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions)

```
var q = [
  {$match: query},
  {$group: {_id: '$hash'}},
  {$out: 'tempCollection'}
];

async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    firstCollection.aggregate(q, callback);
  },
  function(callback) {
    secondCollection.aggregate(q, callback);
  },

  ...

], function() {

  // I want to get all from tempCollection (with pagination) here

});
```

Comment: Wrong contruction of your question. `$out` **always** replaces. What do you want to do here really? "Add" both results in a single collection? Or "merge" based on certain common values "accumulating" other values from both results? Also be specific on whether this is the basic node driver or something else like mongoose, or monk or whatever.

Comment: I use Mongoose. I need to get all the distinct hash values in any way (merging or writing in one collection, or etc).

Comment: Pick one. "merge" - means you have a common "key" or fields that make up a "key" and you intend to "increment" other value where the same key is found. "concatenating" - means that you just want both sets of results to end up in a single collection. Note in the latter the "key" really needs to be different, or artificially made.

Comment: If in firstCollection and secondCollection have same "hash" - I need get result only one (unique). So I use aggregation because the mongoose.distinct works as a aggregation wrapper, and have a pipeline stage limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line here is that the [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) option only ever "replaces" output on the target collection. So to do anything else you must work through a client connection rather than just outputting to the server.

Your best option here with mongoose is to step straight into the underlying driver and get access to the [node stream interface](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) as supported by the driver.

Trival example, but it shows the basic way to structure:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/aggtest');

var testSchema = new Schema({},{ "_id": false, strict: false });


var ModelA = mongoose.model( 'ModelA', testSchema ),
    ModelB = mongoose.model( 'ModelB', testSchema ),
    ModelC = mongoose.model( 'ModelC', testSchema );

function processCursor(cursor,target,callback) {

  cursor.on("end",callback);
  cursor.on("error",callback);

  cursor.on("data",function(data) {
    cursor.pause();
    target.update(
      { "_id": data._id },
      { "$setOnInsert": { "_id": data._id } },
      { "upsert": true },
      function(err) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        cursor.resume();
      }
    );
  });
}

async.series(
  [
    // Clean data
    function(callback) {
      async.each([ModelA,ModelB,ModelC],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },

    // Sample data
    function(callback) {
      async.each([ModelA,ModelB],function(model,callback) {
        async.each([1,2,3],function(id,callback) {
          model.create({ "_id": id },callback);
        },callback);
      },callback);
    },

    // Run merge
    function(callback) {
      async.parallel(
        [
          function(callback) {
            var cursor = ModelA.collection.aggregate(
              [
                { "$group": { "_id": "$_id" } }
              ],
              { "batchSize": 25 }
            );

            processCursor(cursor,ModelC,callback)
          },
          function(callback) {

            var cursor = ModelB.collection.aggregate(
              [
                { "$group": { "_id": "$_id" } }
              ],
              { "batchSize": 25 }
            );

            processCursor(cursor,ModelC,callback)
          }
        ],
        callback
      );
    },

    // Get merged
    function(callback) {
      ModelC.find({},function(err,results) {
        console.log(results);
        callback(err);
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Oustide of that, then you are going to need to `$out` to "separate" collections, and then merge them in with a similar `.update()` process, but to keep it "server side" then you need to use [`.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/eval/).

It's not nice, but that is the only way to keep operations on the server. You can also modify this with ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations ( again through the same native `.collection` interface ) for a bit more throughput. But the options come down to "read through the client" or "eval".